# NSWindow problem

Tags: cocoa, macos

Please help me. I set frame to the window like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
// Insert code here to initialize your application 
[window makeKeyWindow];
[window setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 1024, 768) display:YES];
[window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
[window center];
}
```

But real window size: width = 1024, height = 620. I think because my screen size (1280x720).
So, when `[window setContentView:myView]`, myView is disable a part.
I can't solve this problem. Please help me solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Size your content view to fit the space available using `-[NSWindow contentRectForFrameRect:]`. You should also consider sizing your window's frame to fit the available space, as well, such as by using `-[NSScreen visibleFrame]`. Both the Dock and the menu bar eat some space, so you should not expect to have the full screen size available to your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show your window at the maximum size, have a look at [NSWindow](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s `-zoom:` method